# JSONModel NSArray ConvertOnDemand

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, jsonmodel

How can I create a ConvertOnDemand 'NSArray *' using the JSONModel library from the following JSON response: -

```
[
 {"id": 1, "name": "jim"},
 {"id": 2, "name": "lovy"}
]
```

Please check here if you want to know more JSONModel ConvertOnDemand (https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jsonmodel+convertonDemand).

Comment: do u want to creat array from these dictionary?

Comment: @muku, it is an array of dictionaries. But I too do not undestand the question.

Comment: Yes I want to create an NSArray <ConvertOnDemand> * from this json response, not a simple NSArray.

Comment: Have you read through the docs? http://jsonmodel.com/docs/ Or the README on github https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel   What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using the native `Foundation` framework instead, you could do something like this

```
NSArray *arr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&err];
```

If your JSON is in the form of a string, just convert to `NSData` before calling the above

```
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This solution will give you an `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries`

Comment: thanks, but what I need is an NSArray that Converts on Demand. Please check here for details (https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jsonmodel+convertonDemand)

Answer (score 0):

May be [BWJSONMatcher](https://github.com/BurrowsWang/BWJSONMatcher) is what you are looking for.

Declare your data model that matches your json string:

```
@interface YourDataModel : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@end
```

Then your can use [BWJSONMatcher](https://github.com/BurrowsWang/BWJSONMatcher) to convert the json string to an NSArray which can be directly used in your ViewControllers.

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [BWJSONMatcher matchJSON:jsonString withClass:[YourDataModel class]];
```

Answer (score 0):

ConvertOnDemand is **optional** for your model class, if your entity class is Person class, declare the array property like this,

`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<Person, ConvertOnDemand> *persons;`

`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<Person> *persons;`

For the former one, the persons array type is `JSONModelArray[Person]`, it just means all the person object has conformed Person protocol. For the later one, the type is `NSArray` with unconfirmed objects, but they are really Person type.